# EXTJS how to focus checkcolumn cell

Tags: grid, focus, extjs4

Been working with the checkcolumn plugin, I've discovered that when I click on any cell in that column, it doesn't highlight. I'm going to assume this means that the cell is not focused.

This has the effect of that when another cell receives focus, the grid scrolls back up to its last/current focused cell whenever I click on *any* cell in the checkbox column. I could scroll halfway down and click on a checkbox and if a textfield at the start of the grid had focus the grid will scroll back up.

Strangely enough when I navigate using the keyboard the cell is highlighted as expected, so this is a mouse-only issue which I don't understand. Where would I add code to focus on the cell in the checkcolumn?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like processEvent method in the checkcolumn returns false to stop selection on purpose:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/source/CheckColumn.html#Ext-ux-CheckColumn

I don't know why that is and what would be the ramification if it returned true - but it possible to override it and see I guess :)

Comment: Thanks, this allows the highlighting to happen, but it doesn't actually change the focus on to the next element. The grid still scrolls up/down to the last clicked-on cell. In fact, after commenting out the 'return false' the checkbox cells counted as a focused cell, whereas they did not before (e.g. I click on a checkbox, scroll waaaaay down, click on another checkbox, grid scrolls right back up top to the previous checkbox. It didn't happen when 'return false' was in place, only when I clicked on other non-checkbox cells). Frustrating!

Comment: you know this might be a bug, see if you can find a similarly reported issue on Sencha forums and file a bug for it.